# Can you add a different mail option to Joomla e.g with a plugin?

Tags: plugin, jmail

I'm wanting to create a plugin to send e-mails using API methods (e.g. mailgun API or others)

Is there a recommended way to do this? Can anyone point me at any good practice / hints & tips ?

I'm guessing a system plugin would be the start? then onAfterInitialise or something? and something like JLoader::register() ?

Or is there a way to config so that there is a new option in the config? and then if "mailer" = "mailgun" use this plugin functions ?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, Kiran? I need a Mailgun extension too.

Comment: no sorry kinda got side tracked with other things